# How to write a function that gradually stops at a certain value?

Tags: functions

I need a function that looks like this:

[image]

It starts off like a linear function, but as $a$ increases, $x$ slowly starts to stop at $b$. I'm guessing I should have an extra parameter that describes how smooth the curve is, perhaps in relation to $a$?

Since I want the function to start linearly, I guess I should probably have $a$ and then subtract a value that slowly increases as $a$ increases? But how do I constrain it to $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. A simple way is $ba\over{b+a}$

Comment: Works wonderfully! Just because I'm curious - can you show another way to do it?

Comment: yes, but first let me change your notation a bit : call the vertical axis $y$, call the horizontal axis $x$ ( this is the way most people are comfortable with). Now the function I proposed was $y(x)={b x \over {b+x}}$. Another example is $y(x)= {bx\over{\sqrt {b^2+x^2}}}$